# Planning your projects? 

Tags: planning, project

Do you use a specific program to plan your projects?

We use project planning software. We use it to both plan specific projects and booking our studios. It's by no means the perfect tool but it works decent.

What I like is the visual overview over longer time periods. Calendars like iCal don't have views for quarters/years/custom. Looking at a month at a time is no good when doing long term planning.

Any other suggestions on alternative planning tools.

Answer (score 1):

I use **pivotal tracker**. 
It's not really a calendar based tool, but more a project resource management type thing.

These tracker type programs are often used for programming. For bug checking, beta testing and deployment etc, but I just steal the terms and give them my own meaning.

For instance in pivotal tracker (which also runs on iphone etc. . super handy)
I set up a project, then the individual tasks, then checklists that each task involves. The task is rated by difficultly - i.e how long I guess it will take me to accomplish. 
If it is something that the producer of the project has asked for its a FEATURE, if its something that they havent but it is needed (i.e location recording, research) its a CHORE. 
If theres some audio clean up needing doing its a BUG. 
A cheap way of using a tool not meant for sound, but its proven quite interesting.

Theres also the brilliant completion section, meaning you can process what you have delivered, if it was accepted, and if not, why not?

Between this, and a copious amount of colourful mind mapping tools out their, I can try manage as much as possible.

although we all know it comes down to a lot of caffeine and 2 dozen post it notes in the end. :D

Cam

Answer (score 0):

While this is a great suggestion and we are attempting to implement it, I was wondering if anyone uses a similar method that is slightly more customizable and can be more tailored to sound supervision and project organization. I have been doing the spreadsheet method and am finding myself wanting a better option.

Cheers !